# Shiny Server Stopped working after switching EC2 Instance State

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I have a deployed shiny app that was setup on an AWS t2 medium EC2 instance, everything was working fine until recently I decided to switch my instance type to a t2 micro. Immediately after switching the instance type and restarting as t2 micro, the url(....eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/myapp) for my shiny app shows 'Page Not Found'. I've tried switching my instance back to a t2 medium but still getting the same error when trying to access my shiny app. The shiny app files, R installation and packages all seem to be fine regardless of which instance I'm switching to, the shiny server in ubuntu also shows it is running without problems. Please let me know if there's any good ways to troubleshoot this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you use elastic ip or load balancer? Could be link to network / security groups...

Comment: no I haven't used those yet, and also nothing has changed on the network security groups either (all traffic allowed inbound/outbound on port 3838)